# Firefox addon: contentaccessible=yes

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

Is it dangerous to have the "contentaccessible=yes" flag in your Firefox addon? And is there anyway to limit it to just be  contentaccessible=yes for one image?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's a bit dangerous but manageable if you are careful.  And AFAIK you can only make an entire directory accessible.

You'll want to create a directory where web accessible things can reside.  Your chrome.manifest ends up looking something like this:

```
content   your-add-on             chrome/skin/web/ contentaccessible=yes
```

Put your image in the `chrome/skin/web/` directory and it will be available and it will be available like this:

```
<img src="chrome://your-add-on/content/installed.png"/>
```